# Can the CPU performance be monitored on the server using external tools without installing any software installed in the server, using the server IP

Tags: performance, server, monitoring

Is there a way we can monitor the CPU utilisation of a linux server where my website has been hosted using any external tools available without installing any software on the server (i.e just using the IP address of the server).

Please let me know if that would be possible.

Comment: If the server is just running a normal web server, all you can do from the outside is measure response times.  You can't tell whether a slow response is due to CPU, disk, or network.  (And BTW, the web server is already software.  If a machine was just running a kernel, you could ping it but it wouldn't accept TCP connections at all.  If it wasn't running any software, it could only boot to the BIOS...)

Answer (score 0):

If your web tool includes some kind of performance monitor plugin you might set it up on a hidden page. But your tool might also include some kind of monitoring for your site.

But how much you can use the data you get returned is another matter as you most likely are run in a Docker in a WM that is optimal for the provider (and not for you).